# Ubuntu Core Snappy on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: application-development

Has anyone successfully created an image of Snappy for RPi3? Any SD cards that I've loaded with the Snappy for RPi images, that I've been able to find, don't work with the RPi3, only on my RPi2. I found this reference: "You need to replace the contents of /boot and /lib/modules to get your old SDCard to boot on a new RPi3". But I didn't see any guidance about what to replace those with, or how to maintain it being a Ubuntu Core Snappy install.

Comment: I posted a similar question about using `Ubuntu 14.04 ARM` on the `rpi3`. I'm willing to bet they share the same answer so I'll let you know if I hear anything.

Comment: My answer came from @AndroidDev for a newly compiled version of Ubuntu MATE. Note, this still uses `apt-get` because it's no snappy. Regardless, here's the link: https://ubuntu-mate.org/blog/ubuntu-mate-for-raspberry-pi-3/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Snappy Core available for Raspberry Pi 3?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/758172/is-snappy-core-available-for-raspberry-pi-3)

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu Core immage for Pi3 can be found here:

http://releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/16/ubuntu-core-16-pi3.img.xz

Info source: https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/raspberry-pi-2/

Personally I use a server image until I will get used to snaps:

http://www.finnie.org/software/raspberrypi/ubuntu-rpi3/ubuntu-16.04-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi3.img.xz

Info source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi

Answer (score 0):

ubuntu-core 16.04 is almost here now, you can find the it here: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/xenial/daily-preinstalled/current/