# Is Snappy Core available for Raspberry Pi 3/4?

Tags: ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

If it's available, I can't seem to find it on the site. If it's not, can someone please link me to as much information as possible so that I can track progress on developments? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rpi3 image will be available very shortly (once the Ubuntu core series 16 images are beeing released).

To keep posted on such announcement, best is to sign up for the snappy mailing list https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/support/ this is where you will hear the latest on the topic and / or find people to collaborate with on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

Canonical has released official Ubuntu Core images for Raspberry Pi.

- <s>[Ubuntu Core 16](http://releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/16/ubuntu-core-16-pi3.img.xz) is based on Ubuntu 16.04, and is supported for 5 years.</s>
- [Ubuntu Core 18](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/18/stable/current/ubuntu-core-18-armhf+raspi.img.xz) for Raspberry Pi 2/3/4 is based on Ubuntu 18.04, and is supported for 10 years.

A new release of Ubuntu Core is released every 2 years on even numbered years (2016, 2018, etc.).

The installation instructions from [Raspberry Pi | Ubuntu developer portal](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/raspberry-pi-2/) are as follows.

> Start by downloading the Ubuntu Core 16 image for Raspberry Pi 3 to your `~/Downloads` folder.
>
> Insert your SD card, unmount it and run:
>
> ```
> xzcat ~/Downloads/ubuntu-core-16-pi3.img.xz | sudo dd of=/dev/sdX bs=32M
> sync
> ```
>
> *Note:* replace `/dev/sdX` with the device name of your SD card (e.g. `/dev/mmcblk0`, `/dev/sdg1` ...)
>
> Eject the SD card physically from your PC, and insert the SD card in your Raspberry Pi.
>
> **Notes**
>
> - If your SD card is mounted when you insert it into your computer (you will know it if the file manager automatically opens a window showing the card's contents), you must manually unmount it before writing the Ubuntu Core image to it. Either eject your SD card from the file manager, or from the command line: `sudo umount /media/$USER/*`
> - You must specify the path to the disk device representing your SD card in the `dd` command above. Common device paths for the SD card disk device are either of the form `/dev/sdX` (such as `/dev/sdb`, not `/dev/sdb1`!) or `/dev/mmcblk0` (not `/dev/mmcblk0p1`!)
> - Ensure there is no data you care about on the SD card before running the `dd` command above.
>
> **Prerequisites for booting Ubuntu Core**
>
> An Ubuntu SSO account is required to setup the first user on the board.
>
> - Start by creating an [Ubuntu SSO account](https://login.ubuntu.com/).
> - Import an SSH Key into your Ubuntu SSO account [on this page](https://login.ubuntu.com/ssh-keys).
> - Instructions to generate an SSH Key can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys).
> - You will need a keyboard, monitor or a serial cable plugged into the board to be able to go through the first boot process and complete device.

Answer (score 0):

core 16 is almost finished; see: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/xenial/daily-preinstalled/current/

Answer (score 0):

As of 2017 it's officially available at http://releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/16/