# Ubuntu Core on Pi 4

Tags: ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

I'm doing a project with a Pi for an IoT solution. I'd really like to go for the Pi4, but when will Core be released for Raspberry Pi 4?
I know about the unofficial build, but as this is a commercial product, I need the official release.

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/download/iot/raspberry-pi will provide official Ubuntu Server releases for Raspberry pi 4.

Comment: I know this, but I need the Core distribution, not server!

Comment: I don't know, but the next Ubuntu Core release may not be till Ubuntu Core 20 comes out next year.  There are some issues being worked out with 19.10 on Pi 4 (they exist in raspbian too), and I suspect they'll be worked out there; Core is based on LTS releases; however  Ubuntu Server releases are official too.

Comment: Thanks, I will go with the Pi3 then, as I cannot wait that long :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Snappy Core available for Raspberry Pi 3/4?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/758172/is-snappy-core-available-for-raspberry-pi-3-4)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the universal Raspberry Pi Ubuntu Core 18 image (for pi 2/3/4)

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/18/stable/current/ubuntu-core-18-armhf+raspi.img.xz